# Using .format() with tuples instead of dictionaries

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, format

I have this line in my code that uses dictionary:

```
print("{} {}".format(holiday["data"].strftime("%d/%m"), holiday["description"]))
```

I don't know if it is more elegant, but I want to make this example to be applied as a tuple.

Comment: Can we see more of that code? It looks like `holiday` isn't being defined correctly.

Comment: `holiday` is a tuple not a dictionary. Show us the initialization.

Comment: Please show the initialization of the variable named `holiday`

Comment: Yeah, you're indexing it with a string, which probably means it's supposed to be a dictionary instead of a tuple.

Comment: oh, that's right, it really was supposed to be a dictionary. I forgot to write one of the lines. I will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two values are in a tuple, you can use the fact that `datetime` and `date` objects support formatting with `str.format()` *directly*:

```
holiday_tuple = (datetime.date(2015, 3, 1), 'some description')
print("{:%d/%m} {}".format(*holiday_tuple))
```

The `*arg` syntax applies the two elements in `holiday_tuple` as separate arguments.

You can also have the string template do the extraction:

```
print("{0[0]:%d/%m} {0[1]}".format(holiday_tuple))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> holiday_tuple = (datetime.date(2015, 3, 1), 'some description')
>>> print("{:%d/%m} {}".format(*holiday_tuple))
01/03 some description
>>> print("{0[0]:%d/%m} {0[1]}".format(holiday_tuple))
01/03 some description
```

I'd have done something similar with the dictionary; rather than extract the keys from the dictionary in the arguments, have these extracted either by using `**kwargs` syntax or with using the indexing syntax:

```
holiday_dictionary = {'data': datetime.date(2015, 3, 1), 'description': 'some description')
print("{data:%d/%m} {description}".format(**holiday_dictionary))
print("{0[data]:%d/%m} {0[description]}".format(holiday_dictionary))
```

Comment: my date tuple is written like this `datetime.date(2014, 1, 1)`. How should I write it then? It gave me this error when I wrote it `ValueError: Invalid format specifier`

Comment: @ArrowsX: right, and that's exactly what I used here; the only difference is how I imported the `datetime.date()` object.

Comment: It's the same thing, ArrowsX. He just used a different import style and date.

Comment: @ArrowsX: adjusted the sample; only the import and how I reference `datetime.date()` changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try use integers indices, depending on which index corresponds to which value. If your holiday variable is a tuple, that is. Otherwise, you should create a dictionary and use your original line of code.

```
print("{} {}".format(holiday[0].strftime("%d/%m"), holiday[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry about tuples here, if indeed you do have a `dict`, then you can use `str.format` to do it directly from the `dict`, eg:

```
from datetime import datetime

holiday = {
    'data': datetime.today(),
    'description': 'Would love one'
}

res = '{data:%d/%m} {description}'.format(**holiday)
# 01/03 Would love one
```